# Informatica. I have workflow with 5 sessions. How to limit no of rows for each session and in second run how to pick the different records?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have a flat file (.csv) as source with two fields . I have workflow with 5 sessions . Each session should pick 200 records and total 1000 records updated to webservice. In the second run it should pick the records from 1001 to 2000 , here I am providing the sample count. How do we limit rows in each session and how to pick different records from first run.

```
wf_start time-> session1(flatfile)-->s2,s3,s4,s5,s6(concurrent sessions)

Concurrent session mapping:
```

[image: mapping]

[image: filter condition to limit rows]

Is there a way to get another set of 1000 records in the next run from same file in the second workflow run?

Is there way to fetch another set of 1000 records in the next run we can configure?

Answer (score 1):

You need a table to store the 1000rows that already processed.

Main map will have this new table as target. And it will b used as lkp and filter as well.
New table will have only key column of main table and a flag `already processed`.
Your mapping will b like this

```
Sq --> exp (lkp on newtable) --> fil ( if lookup return null- pass) --...> originalTgt
                               > Newtable
```

Lookup will be on key column and already processed<> Yes.

Comment: Yup thats one of the way. and we can also use fltafile look up as well or after finishing the first run we can run the first session which fetches flat file on some filter condition so that we can get records other than updated one.